# Unexpected value in JSON reposnse after receiving in CoffeeScript

Tags: json, coffeescript

I use simple http client in my coffee script. It should send request to server which responds with JSON, I do it and try to parse response, but get strange result:

```
http = require 'http'

http.get { host: 'myurl' }, (res) ->
    data = ''
    res.on 'data', (chunk) ->
        data += chunk
        log 'Body: ' + chunk
    log 'Data: ' + data
```

Actual result from server looks like this:

```
config{
    username: login,
    password: password
}
```

But I get such output:

```
Body: config{username:login,password: password}
Data: config{username:login,password: password}:unexpected
```

When I try to parse data in JSON and use it, I get an error, and I suppose it is cause I get token ':enexpected'. Why it appears here?

P.S. Write code by memory, cause original source not available now, so here could be so syntax errors, but don`t take them into account in original code everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if that is a related issue, but you are trying to print the data immediately, without waiting for the request to complete. What you should do is to wait for the `end` event:

```
http.get { host: 'myurl' }, (res) ->
  data = ''
  res.on 'data', (chunk) ->
    data += chunk
    log 'Body: ' + chunk
  # request might - and might not - be finished yet
  # log 'Data: ' + data
  res.on 'end', ->
    # request is certainly done
    log 'Complete: ' + data
```

If you got the data complete the way you posted it, it was either accidental, or you were already using this handler.

Comment: It is not connected with async request. Such suffix 'undefined' sometimes noticed in output of some other vars.